# Magento 2.2.5 get product and product image urls store vise

Tags: product, store-view, magento-2.2.5, geturl

I want to send all product data of my store into **Elasticsearch**. In that I am facing one challenge to retrieve product url and product image/video urls store vise.

For example:-

My default store URL :- https://localhost/magento2

My UK store URL :- https://localhost/magento2/ukstore

How can I get the all product url of **ukstore** which should look like https://localhost/magento2/ukstore/product1/.

Does anyone has any idea regarding this? Any help into this will be appreciated.

Thanks,